# php eval for calculation shutterspeed in variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need to export a mysql database 50.000 records that contains shutterspeeds into a json files for the use of exiftool.

But i’m getting this error: syntax error, unexpected token ";" at the eval line

All the shutterspeeds are as 1/125 or 1/60 in the database.
The shutterspeed is in $row[1]

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_images)){    
            // change 1/125 to 0,008
            $myvalue = $row[1];
             if (strpos($myvalue, '/') !== false)  {
                    $exposure = $myvalue;
            }else{
                eval("\$exposure = $myvalue;");
            }
```

Comment: there is something wrong in `$myvalue` that can't be evaluated and provides a syntax error. What is the exact value at the moment you have the error?

Comment: by the way, I'm pretty sure you want to invert your condition and use `eval()` when you've found a `/`, not the opposite

Comment: Thank you Cid, I have used a :
  echo $myvalue."-".$row[15]."<br>";
To see at what record the error happens. Until now the next value is 1/125.

Comment: So I have found the record where it happens, but $row[1] is empty in the database.
Then it schould not go to eval() …

Comment: Cid, it works !! Forgot to change the condition. Thank you

Comment: The use of `eval` here makes me cringe. `$parts = explode('/', $row[1]); $exposure = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[0] / $parts[1] : $parts[0];`